# How to debug memleak in call from Go code to C code?

Tags: c, go

I have code in Go which internally makes lots of library calls which is in C. I have written the interface which makes the transformations from Go to C and vice-versa. The library does not have any leak as I have been using it for a long time. I am definitely missing something in the interface level.

Tried using valgrind but unable to pinpoint the source of the leak. Attaching the leak console logs from valgrind.

```
==59864== 24 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 565 of 883
==59864==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==59864==    by 0x7E14B3: _cgo_9699bfde5761_Cfunc__Cmalloc (_cgo_export.c:27)
==59864==    by 0x46A2AF: runtime.asmcgocall (in /home/sumanb/work/BangDB-Core/golang/ecommerce/ecommerce)
==59864==    by 0xC00006E17F: ???
==59864==    by 0xAF97E47: ???
==59864==    by 0x466101: runtime.(*mcache).nextFree.func1 (in /home/sumanb/work/BangDB-Core/golang/ecommerce/ecommerce)
==59864==    by 0x4041D7F: ???
==59864==    by 0xC00019484D: ???
==59864==    by 0x106F: ???
==59864==    by 0xC00000197F: ???
==59864==    by 0x442ADF: ??? (in /home/sumanb/work/BangDB-Core/golang/ecommerce/ecommerce)
==59864== 
==59864== 48 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 674 of 883
==59864==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==59864==    by 0x7E14B3: _cgo_9699bfde5761_Cfunc__Cmalloc (_cgo_export.c:27)
==59864==    by 0x46A2AF: runtime.asmcgocall (in /home/sumanb/work/BangDB-Core/golang/ecommerce/ecommerce)
==59864==
```

Comment: So, you want everyone to guess the problem w/o looking at that interface you're talking about?